# Can we put verification while schema creation in mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a new schema in mongoose and trying to verify different inputs eg ip and pwd. 
We can have the verification in UI part but can we do it again in back-end?
Below is the example code:-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ServerSchema = new Schema({
    serverIp: { type : String , required : true },
    Name:  { type: String,  required : true },
    serverType: {type: String , required : true },
    created_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

I have never worked on back-end part, so please excuse if this is a novice question.

Comment: Mongoose is a backend framework. It will perform the data validation on the backend only, and not on the frontend.

Comment: @str: that's what my question is sir. I am saying that we can do the verification in front end means through **angular.js**. But can we do it through mongoose too.

Comment: See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even use custom regular expressions to perform your validation. For example like this:

```
    var userSchema = new Schema({
  phone: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        return /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(v);
      },
      message: '{VALUE} is not a valid phone number!'
    },
    required: [true, 'User phone number required']
  }
});
```

Check out mongoose [validation docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

Comment: JavaEvgen: This is working fine for phone number. As d{3} will accept minimum 3 character but in ip it can be 1-3. I tried using d{1-3} but it's not working. Do let me know if this can be done.

Comment: try this one: `/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/$`

Comment: It's working fine with `/\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}/`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to hear my answer helped you. Thanx